# One tape Turing machine for doubling 1's

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, turing-machines

I am reading an introductory text on Turing machines( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) and I have some questions. The first one is the following: Prove that there is a single-tape Turing machine that doubles words of the form $1^n$ (result 1 to the 2n power), and works $O(nlogn)$ clock cycles. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried but I couldn't find the clock cycles.

Comment: So where did you get the question from? It's not on the Wikipedia page. My intuition says that it is not possible, but, I could well be wrong.

Comment: I saw in a collection of exercises. I solved the first part, but I couldn't find the running time.

Comment: It makes it a bit difficult for us to help if you don't quote or reference the actual problem you are trying to solve( (your question doesn't have two parts).

Comment: Part 1: existence of machine, part 2: running time.

Comment: That isn't actually how existence proofs work, but never mind. Where did you get the question from?

Comment: Unfirtunately I couldn't find its link

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/143744/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4247067/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).